# Position absolute não ocupa 100% do pai

Tags: css, css3

Porque uma div com position absolute não ocupa 100% da largura do pai se couber, porque quebra a linha antes? Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```css
.segura{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}
.caixa{
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="segura">
   <div class="caixa">
       dfdf fsdfsd dsf d
   </div>
</div>
```

O certo era a caixa preta ficar sem essa quebra de linha, o que fazer para quebrar a linha apenas se chegar no limite da largura?

Comment: Não entendi, você quer que o quadrado preto fique desse tamanho, mas não quebre a linha?

Comment: Não, o html quebrou a linha seu eu pedir, mesmo cabendo o texto todo em uma única linha. Essa quebra foi automática. E não queria essa quebra (apenas se precisar) @LeandroAngelo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma opção para resolver isso é o alinhamento com `flex`, pois assim vc alinha o elemento filho com `margin:auto` e não com `top` `left`, abaixo vou explicar o problema mais detalhadamente.

```css
.segura{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  display: flex;
}
.caixa{
  margin: auto;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
 <div class="segura">
   <div class="caixa">
       dfdf fsdfsd dsf d
   </div>
</div>
```

---

Agora a explicação do seu problema.

O que acontece é que quando vc usa `transform:translate` vc esta ajusta o elemento filho no próprio eixo e não no eixo do pai! Tendo isso em mente perceba que quando vc joga a `.caixa` *(que é mais larga que 50% da largura do pai)*, 50% para esquerda ele quebra a linha!

Para entender melhor veja nesse Gif que ao movimentar a `.caixa` no `left` ela vai se quebrando ou não, já mexendo no eixo `X` do `transform:translate` nada acontece, pois essas medidas são referentes ao próprio eixo!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na verdade a `.caixa` está quebrando a linha na margem direita do pai. Depois disso vc desloca o elemento "*virtualmente*" no próprio eixo, porém a linha continua quebrada por ter atingido a lateral do pai.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**DICA:** Se o seu texto for apenas uma linha vc pode colocar no `white-space: nowrap;` Mas só serve se o texto tiver apenas uma linha!

Veja como fica:

```css
.segura{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}
.caixa{
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="segura">
   <div class="caixa">
       dfdf fsdfsd dsf d
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Entendi, mas isso não me ajuda, pois o .segura é 100% de largura no meu caso (responsivo), teria que pensar outra maneira de resolver....

Comment: @caiocafardo Cara vc pode diminuir o padding... ou até mesmo o font-size! O que acontece que que quando vc joga a .caixa pro centro do .segura a palavra "dsf" não cabe, ela quebra a linha. Veja o código que alterei agora na edição

Comment: Na verdade cabe sim, fiz um teste, ele ta quebrando pelo que percebi pela forma que fiz ele alinhar ao centro: transform: translate(-50%, -50%); Mas não posso alterar as medidas (padding fonte) no meu site, pois é responsivo, pode não quebrar com a fonte que colocar em uma resolução e em outra quebrar, teria que achar uma solução mesmo.

Comment: @caiocafardo estou pensando em uma alternativa aqui...

Comment: Valeu, tirei até o padding no meu exemplo pra não confundir. Tem outras formas de alinhar ao centro, mas aí a div absolute fica com 100% de width, o que não pode acontecer também.

Comment: @caiocafardo Pode ser usando flex?

Comment: Claro! Funcionando pode ser de qualquer jeito!

Comment: white-space: nowrap; também não da, pois o nome vem de banco de dados, pode ter 5 caracteres ou 300...

Comment: @caiocafardo da uma olhada no primeiro exemplo com flex que acabei de editar. Vou fazer uma explicação melhor tb de pq o texto quebra acho que descobri!

Comment: Perfeito com flex!

Comment: @caiocafardo agora sim a resposta está completa! Se te interessar depois da uma olhada na explicação da linha quebrada